# Dagre svg horizontal scrollbar

Tags: svg, dagre-d3, dagre

I have created a directed top-bottom graph with dagre/d3.
But in some cases the graph is too wide to fit on the screen.
I want to add a horizontal scrollbar on the page, but I am somewhat new to front-end development and I can't seem to find out how I can do this.

I have added a small code snippet. The graph is stored in the svg object.

Any help would be appreciated!

[code_snipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLP2m.png)

Comment: the easiest was to create scrollbars is to create them via html i.e. use a <div> with overflow: scroll. The embed your SVG and make sure it's bigger than the div.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks a lot, this worked fine! The only thing is that the horizontal scrollbar is visible all the time (because I set the width of the SVG to 300%). But I can live with that.